# WordPress keep redirecting me to random URLs

Tags: permalinks, urls, errors, 404-error

When I go to my homepage, http://example.com, I *sometimes* get redirected to http://example.com/SXKSLW/ or some other random URL along that pattern that yields 404 page.

I do not remember doing anything special. Tried to disable most of the plugins (except the ones that are installed after the issue has been noticed) with no avails.

This issue also observed when I am at wp-admin, rendering the url to example [.] com/SJDKEW/wp-admin/... ---> obviously to another 404.

Any inputs are welcomed. Thank you

Comment: You've confirmed you don't have malware? You can run your site through https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ or another malware scanner to check.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings, make sure you've specified the Wordpress URL.

Settings > General > WordPress Address (URL)

Alternatively go into your Wordpress database and check :)

Comment: Done both of them. The characters that are randomly inserted into the URL is random. I could not find any similarities anywhere in the database - at least in the table that I suspect (e.g. post)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons your home page address could forward to another URL.

First of all, disable all of your plugins and check if the problem is still happening. If it is still happening, you can rule out all of your plugins. If the problem does not happen when all plugins have been disabled, then you should selectively turn on one plugin at a time to figure out which one is causing the issue.

It's possible that an existing plugin, that was there before the issue started, could cause the error, most likely after an update (or an error) was introduced.

As Bradly mentioned in his answer, also verify that the Wordpress Address is still set properly under Settings > General > WordPress Address (URL).

Lastly, if it's not a plugin or the Wordpress Address, your site may have been hacked, or an error has been introduced in the tables or template file. You should thoroughly check the code for the home page template, and your tables to verify if something is wrong there.

For the tables, open PHPMyAdmin on your server, if you have access to it, and browse the `wp_options` table for the `home` field under `option_name`. Wordpress Address defines this field, but it can't hurt to verify it if you're still having issues.

Comment: Also, switch to one of the WordPress default themes (Twenty Ten, Twenty Eleven, Twenty Twelve) to rule out theme issues.

Comment: The issue only happens _occasionally_ throughout the site including admin panel (not just home). I can be almost certain it is not plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what's happened is you've changed something that changes the Permalink structure. Visit and update the Permalinks. Backend -> Settings -> Permalinks